# Using AfxRegisterWndClass multiple times to create windows

Tags: winapi, mfc

Is it safe to use `AfxRegisterWndClass(0)` each time you create a temporary Window (say `CWnd`).  Example, you use a `CWnd` as a `MessageBox()` (or to work on some object or select something ,etc..) so it's created and then destroyed several times through the life of the application process (which has its own main window as well).   Or would that create a resource leak?

Comment: Please refer to this [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=vs-2019#remarks-16) *If you call AfxRegisterWndClass multiple times with identical parameters, it only registers a class on the first call. Later calls to AfxRegisterWndClass with identical parameters return the already-registered classname...If you call AfxRegisterWndClass for multiple CWnd-derived classes with identical parameters, instead of getting a separate window class for each class, each class shares the same window class.*

Comment: Window classes are registered per module. Unless you are unloading modules that register window classes, resources aren't reclaimed anyway. That said, re-registering a window class with the same name as an already registered window class (from the same module) returns an `ATOM` to the existing window class.

Comment: Well, I kept ending up on a page that was yellow and didn't have any real details.  I searched Internet and still got same page, now today, I get normal non yellow pages and has the details.   Okay, at least answered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I metioned in the comment, according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=vs-2019#remarks-16):

> If you call `AfxRegisterWndClass` for multiple CWnd-derived classes with
> identical parameters, instead of getting a separate window class for
> each class, each class shares the same window class. This sharing can
> cause problems if the CS_CLASSDC class style is used. Instead of
> multiple CS_CLASSDC window classes, you end up with only one
> CS_CLASSDC window class. All C++ windows that use that class share the
> same DC. To avoid this problem, call `AfxRegisterClass` to register the
> class.

In addition, if you use [`RegisterClassEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexa) in Win32, it does not automatically unregister classes registered by a DLL, so you must explicitly unregister classes when the DLL is terminated. By using `AfxRegisterClass`/`AfxRegisterWndClass` instead of `RegisterClassEx` this is handled automatically for you. For details: [The RegisterClass and AfxRegisterClass Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn001-window-class-registration?view=vs-2019#the-registerclass-and-afxregisterclass-functions)